# How to set firebase notification on WearOs

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, wear-os

I'm building an application and want to receive firebase notification on both mobile and wear app, both app having the same package name. I've using FirebaseMessagingService class in both mobile app and wear app. Mobile app receiving notification successfully while wear app not getting any notification. I do google too but not find any relevant solution.

Any help will appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Wear OS can only show notifications but not receive them. The Android OS of the linked device is responsible for receiving the notifications, and while showing them, it automatically duplicates the notification to be shown on the Wear OS device. To avoid duplication, you should explicitly [bridge](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/bridger) notifications to the Wear OS device.

Also, Wear OS can construct and show notifications by itself in response to some triggering event or just by timer, etc..

As your question lacks the implementation details the only thing I can provide you with is theoretical/documentation data - I think you will be able to resolve your issue with it, though.

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, As you ask for implementation details, so I want a better approach or any working example or code snippet. I've already read those links you provided, but I don't get any help.

Answer (score 0):

Wear OS can receive firebase messages the same way a regular android device does. You just need the firebase token which your device gets automatically after initialisation from firebase.

You probably don't want the wear app to have the same package name as the mobile app, how would you distinguish those two apps?

Maybe give more information of what you are doing.